# Trying to pass mock data into functional component and iterate over array to display attribute in span, getting type errors can't access the mock data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React/TypeScript Component that I'm trying to import mock data into and then iterate over it to display a specific attribute in a span element.

The issues I'm running into are that I can't seem to pass the mock data into my component to iterate over it and at the same time I'm also getting weird type errors that seem to suggest that I'm either using the type definitions of my data or the data itself for my props but never both.

I created a CodeSandbox to highlight these issues and I included my main component where I'm seeing the errors below:

[image: Edit ecstatic-hoover-wcyjb]

`Current Component`

```
import React from 'react';
import contacts from '../../mock-data/contacts-mock-data';
import { Contacts, ContactGroup } from '../../services/contacts-client';

type Props = {
  contacts: Contacts[];
  contactGroups: ContactGroup[];
};

export const ContactGroupsSection = (props: Props) => {
  const { contacts, contactGroups } = props

  let groups = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < contacts.contactGroups.length; i++) {
      return <span>{contacts.contactGroups.contactGroup}</span>;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>{groups}</div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [tweaked your codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-clarke-cgdrg?file=/src/contact-groups.tsx) to pass the data into your component as you suggested.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { ContactGroupsSection } from "./contact-groups";
import contacts from "./contacts-mock-data";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <ContactGroupsSection contacts={contacts} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

contact-groups.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Contacts } from "./contact-types";

type Props = {
  contacts: Contacts;
};

export const ContactGroupsSection = ({ contacts }) => {
  const groups = contacts.contactGroups.map(contactGroup => (
    <span>{contactGroup.contactGroup}</span>
  ));

  return <div>{groups}</div>;
};
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice! The only problem I'm seeing now is that I'm getting type errors in my original app for contacts and contactGroup at this part ```export const ContactGroupsSection = ({ contacts }) => {
  const groups = contacts.contactGroups.map(contactGroup => (
    <span>{contactGroup.contactGroup}</span>
  ));```  saying they ```have the implicit type of any``` any idea on how to fix that by using the Type Definitions?

Comment: If I'm understanding the problem correctly, you just need to specify the type of the object you are passing to `ContactGroupsSection`.  Change the prop to something like `{ contacts }: Props`.  That way you are being explicit about what type of props object you are expecting.  Hope that helps!